# Newbie at Java - why does this not compile?

Tags: java, arrays

Tearing my hair out with this now. It's my second program in Java and I tried to extend a simple Dog class into an array of Dog class. I cannot see what is wrong with this but the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Dogprint.main(Dogprint.java:5)
```

---

```
public class Dogprint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog[] dog1 = new Dog[2];

        dog1[0].setbreed("poodle");
        dog1[0].setsize(2);
        dog1[1].setbreed("Alsation");
        dog1[1].setsize(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
            System.out.println(dog1[i].getsize());
            System.out.println(dog1[i].getbreed());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Dog {
    private int size;
    private String breed;

    public void setbreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public void setsize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getsize() {
        return size;
    }

    public String getbreed() {
        return breed;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it compiles fine - what you're seeing is a runtime exception of type `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `Dog[] dog1 = {new Dog(), new Dog()};` This may not work for older versions of Java, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to use the correct terminology - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You created an array of `Dog`s, but you didn't create the `Dog` objects to go into the array.  Java initialized all elements to `null`.  Initialize the elements explicitly, by using `new Dog()`.

```
Dog[] dog1 = new Dog[2];

dog1[0] = new Dog();
dog1[0].setbreed("poodle");
dog1[0].setsize(2);
dog1[1] = new Dog();
dog1[1].setbreed("Alsation");
dog1[1].setsize(5);
```

Comment: Many thanks! I can go to bed now and sleep soundly - it runs fine!